# docker container prune; only remove containers stopped before given timestamp

Tags: docker

[docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/) supports filtering to only remove containers **created** before a given timestamp. Is there any magic that would allow me to only remove containers **stopped** (exited) before a given timestamp? Or in other words, I'd like to be able to specify a min-stopped-age (where 0 = the time the container stopped) of containers to prune. For example, I'd like to remove all containers that have been stopped for 2+ hours.

Comment: Are you looking for some bash script or a code with some language?